# Error while finding object's index in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I've an array with some properties. When I try to find an object's index I'm getting error TypeError: Error #1009. I'm using Flash CS6.

Here's my array:

```
var squareArr:Object  = {
     a1: {
          piece: wr1_txt,
          pieceLoc: {  
            x: "-3",
            y: "347"
          }
     },
     b1: {
          piece: wn1_txt,
          pieceLoc: {  
            x: "47",
            y: "347"
          }
     },
...
```

Below code is giving me error #1009 while I want it to return a1:

```
trace (squareArr.indexOf(wr1_txt));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't `indexOf()` of an Object, you should instead do a property lookup cycle.

```
var s:String;
var found:Boolean=false;
for (s in squareArr) {
    if (squareArr[s].piece == wr1_txt) { // YAY found it
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) trace(s); else trace("Not found!");
```

And the `s` will be your index.

Of course, don't forget to parse for errors, if your target is not found, you should not say the last index is what contais target.

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for my english. I couldn't understand "if your target is not found, you should not say the last index is what contais target". trace(s) outputs nothing.

Comment: Hmm, then declare the var not in the cycle but before it, so that the variable will still be accessible after cycling.

Comment: but now says Not found! trace(wr1_txt); // outputs [object TextField]

Comment: ActionScript 3.0 uses variable hoisting, so it doesn't matter if he declares a var inside or outside of a for loop; it still compiles as though it's declared at the beginning of the function.